# PHP - Не получается грамотно сделать цикл для загрузки нескольких изображений

Tags: php, циклы

Код загрузки изображений на сервер в данный момент загружает только одну, а нужно чтобы загружал несколько (в HTML атрибуте уже установлено multiple)

```
<?php

$filePath  = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$errorCode = $_FILES['upload']['error'];

if ($errorCode !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK || !is_uploaded_file($filePath)) {
    $errorMessages = [
        UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE   => 'Размер файла превысил значение upload_max_filesize в конфигурации PHP.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => 'Размер загружаемого файла превысил значение MAX_FILE_SIZE в HTML-форме.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL    => 'Загружаемый файл был получен только частично.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE    => 'Файл не был загружен.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'Отсутствует временная папка.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'Не удалось записать файл на диск.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => 'PHP-расширение остановило загрузку файла.',
    ];

    $unknownMessage = 'При загрузке файла произошла неизвестная ошибка.';
    $outputMessage = isset($errorMessages[$errorCode]) ? $errorMessages[$errorCode] : $unknownMessage;

    die($outputMessage);
}

$fi = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

$mime = (string) finfo_file($fi, $filePath);

finfo_close($fi);

if (strpos($mime, 'image') === false) die('Можно загружать только изображения.');

$image = getimagesize($filePath);
$limitBytes  = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
$limitWidth  = 1280;
$limitHeight = 768;

if (filesize($filePath) > $limitBytes) die('Размер изображения не должен превышать 5 Мбайт.');
if ($image[1] > $limitHeight)          die('Высота изображения не должна превышать 768 точек.');
if ($image[0] > $limitWidth)           die('Ширина изображения не должна превышать 1280 точек.');

$name = md5_file($filePath);
$extension = image_type_to_extension($image[2]);
$format = str_replace('jpeg', 'jpg', $extension);

if (!move_uploaded_file($filePath, __DIR__ . '/pics/' . $name . $format)) {
    die('При записи изображения на диск произошла ошибка.');
}
```

Comment: Есть кто-то кто может помочь с решением проблемы?

Comment: Документацию читали в http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.multiple.php?

Comment: Я задал вопрос именно для того, чтобы получить помощь, совет, но никак чтобы мне документации сбрасывали.  Зачем комментировать пост если нет конкретного ответа?

Comment: Затем что это комментарий, а не ответ, для уточнения того чем часто пренебрегают авторы вопросов. У вас в коде нет foreach по сброшенным файлам, поэтому ссылка на документацию будет частичной помощью. Давать полный и развёрнутый ответ часто бывает менее полезным нежели дача подсказок, с помощью которых проактивный автор сможет самостоятельно ответить на свой же вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Переписал с некоторыми комментариями. Думаю будет полезно.

```
<?php 

// функция вывода реакции на ошибки
function checkErrorType($file) {
    if ($file['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK || !is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])) {
        $errorMessages = [
            UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE   => 'Размер файла превысил значение upload_max_filesize в конфигурации PHP.',
            UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => 'Размер загружаемого файла превысил значение MAX_FILE_SIZE в HTML-форме.',
            UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL    => 'Загружаемый файл был получен только частично.',
            UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE    => 'Файл не был загружен.',
            UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'Отсутствует временная папка.',
            UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'Не удалось записать файл на диск.',
            UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => 'PHP-расширение остановило загрузку файла.',
        ];

        $unknownMessage = 'Неизвестная ошибка';

        $outputMessage = isset($errorMessages[$file['error']]) ? $errorMessages[$file['error']] : $unknownMessage;

        echo $outputMessage.' при загрузке файла '.$file['name']."\n";
    }
}

// пример из документации который переделывает обычное представление в представление пофайловое
function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}

// смотрим есть ли массив с фйлами
if ($_FILES['upload']) {
    // реструктурируем массив с файлами для удобства
    $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['upload']);

    // перечитываем массив по очереди
    foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
        $filePath  = $file['tmp_name'];
        $errorCode = $file['error'];

        checkErrorType($file);

        $fi = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime = (string) finfo_file($fi, $filePath);

        finfo_close($fi);

        if (strpos($mime, 'image') === false) die('Можно загружать только изображения.');

        $image = getimagesize($filePath);
        $limitBytes  = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
        $limitWidth  = 1280;
        $limitHeight = 768;

        if (filesize($filePath) > $limitBytes) die('Размер изображения не должен превышать 5 Мбайт.');
        if ($image[1] > $limitHeight)          die('Высота изображения не должна превышать 768 точек.');
        if ($image[0] > $limitWidth)           die('Ширина изображения не должна превышать 1280 точек.');

        $name = md5_file($filePath);
        $extension = image_type_to_extension($image[2]);
        $format = str_replace('jpeg', 'jpg', $extension);

        if (!move_uploaded_file($filePath, __DIR__ . '/pics/' . $name . $format)) {
            die('При записи изображения на диск произошла ошибка.');
        }       
    }
}







?>
```

Comment: Вижу изменения, есть в этом логика, но скрипт теперь отдает ошибку 500 и не могу понять почему

Comment: протести код, он выдает ошибку 500

Comment: Прошу прощения, но ты мог бы помочь со своим кодом? Я несколько ошибок нашел из-за чего могло выдавать ошибку 500 исправил, но все равно не работает

Comment: Кто-то может наконец помочь адекватно? Ведь этот портал для того и создан, чтобы можно было найти ответ на интересующий вопрос

Comment: Что в логах, покажи.

Comment: их нет к сожалению

Comment: Ну так надо их включить. Пробуй, поправил то что кинулось в глаза.